# Is $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_5\to\mathbb{Z}_{30},$ $\phi(x)=6x$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Is $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_5\to\mathbb{Z}_{30},$ $\phi(x)=6x$ a homomorphism?

They can help me solve this problem. I know the answer is no. And I think it's a trick that I still don't see

Comment: It's a group homomorphism but not a ring homomorphism. It's at least well defined since multiples of $5$ get sent to multiples of $30$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank you very much, how do I see that it is not a ring homomorphism?

Comment: $1$ gets sent to $6$ which is not the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$

Comment: You tagged this “group-homomorphism”. What do you care about ring homomorphisms? But assuming that’s a mis-tag... does your definition of “ring homomorphism require that multiplicative identities be sent to multiplicative identities?

Comment: I think it is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @Jet Chung $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ is not an integral domain, so, it doesn't matter that $1$ maps to a divisor of zero.

Comment: @Alearner: The issue is not whether it is a zero divisor. Sometimes, people define “rings” in a way that requires the existence of a multiplicative identity, and requires that ring homomorphisms $f\colon R\to S$ must map $1_R$ to $1_S$. If that is the case here, then this cannot be a ring homomorphism, since $f(1_{\mathbb{Z}_5})=6\neq 1_{\mathbb{Z}_{30}}$. But if ring homomorphisms are not requires to take the multiplicative identity to the multiplicative identity, then that’s a different question.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Why? I don't understand. If ring homomorphism is neither onto nor the codomain is an integral domain, then how $1$ map always to unity in codomain ring?

Comment: @Alearner https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ring.pdf

Comment: @Alearner: So, you’ve never mapped $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by sending $x$ to $(x,x)$? Map is not onto, codomain is not an integral domain, and yet that’s an additive and multiplicative function that sends the multiplicative identity of the domain to the multiplicative identity of the codomain (and the domain is an integral domain on top of that). Frankly, I do not even know why you bring up “integral domains”.

Comment: @Alearner For starters, it's [right at the top of the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism).

Comment: @Alearner ? They *did* define a particular map whose homomorphism-ness is being questioned, namely $x\mapsto 6x$; the point is that this is **not** a ring homomorphism according to the more common (unital, and unit-preserving) definition since it doesn't send the multiplicative unit to the multiplicative unit.

Comment: @Alearner: As I said at the very beginning: **if** your definition of “ring” and “ring homomorphism” requires you to send the multiplicative identity to the multiplicative identity, that’s one question; **if** your definition of ring homomorphism **does not** require you to send the multiplicative identity to the multiplicative identity, then that’s a *different* question. And finally, **you** claimed you could not map a ring to a ring that was not an integral domain, with a non-surjective map, and still send the identity of the domain to that of the codomain (cont)

Comment: @Alearner: Or at least, that you couldn’t figure out how. I gave you an explicit example, and now you object because you would rather consider a different map? Now you are just being obtuse. If you don’t know the definitions, or you don’t know that there are multiple possibilities, that’s one thing. But now you object that I gave you an explicit example of the phenomenon you claimed did not occur. So you say, “what if I use a different function?” Well, then you are just whistling in the wind, aren’t you? I don’t care what *you* say; I care what definition the OP is using.

Comment: @Alearner: He pointed you to the Wikipedia page that also includes the requirement that $\phi(1_R)=1_S$. That’s one common way to define both “ring” and “ring homomorphism”.

Comment: I've cleaned up a few comments here, but I'll summarize the remaining comments. It is not clear from the question what sort of homomorphism we are considering. There are two levels of indirection: whether we are to interpret it as a **group** homomorphism (which it is) or a **ring** homomorphism, and **if** it's a ring homomorphism then whether we require $1 \mapsto 1$ in the homorphism. This is described further in Noah's answer. As I write this, the question is closed because it requires more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some ambiguity here.

First of all, the map **is** a *group* homomorphism, which is what is suggested by your tags. If, however, you're asking whether it is a *ring* homomorphism (per the comments), it depends on what definition of ring and ring homomorphism you're using. Specifically, many texts - most, in my experience - include the existence of a **multiplicative unit** as part of the definition of ring, and correspondingly require ring homomorphisms to preserve that unit. Other texts don't make these requirements. When there's a danger of ambiguity the terms "unital ring (homomorphism)" and "non-unital ring (homomorphism)" are used.

For example, consider the set $2\mathbb{Z}$ of even integers with the usual notions of addition and multiplication. This is a non-unital ring; whether or not it's considered a ring outright depends on what text you're using. Relatedly, consider the function $$f: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}: x\mapsto 2x.$$ Both domain and codomain are unital rings, but $f$ itself is only a homomorphism in the non-unital sense. Basically, what we have here is a non-unital ring homomorphism between two non-unital rings which happen to have units. :P More jargonily, the category of unital rings is a **non-full** subcategory of the category of non-unital rings.

But **back to your question**. The map $$\phi:\mathbb{Z}_5\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{30}: x\mapsto 6x$$ is only a ring homomorphism in the non-unital sense, and so - again, in my experience (I'm not an algebraist) - most texts would **not** consider it to be a ring homomorphism.

Comment: It’s really divided; a lot of general abstract algebra books consider both situations, sometimes making a convention, sometimes not (and saying “unital”). Many ring theory books do require unital rings and maps, especially if they work with modules, but ring theorists who do radical theory do not because then most of the constructions lead to “non-rings”.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: As, $6$ is a idempotent in $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$

$\phi(xy)=6xy=(6x)(6y)=\phi(x) \phi(y) $